# TestToken Api not working on mobile first server getting 404 error

Tags: api, testing, ibm-cloud, mobilefirst-server

I am trying to generate TestToken using API http://localhost:9080/testApp/authorization/v1/testtoken on mobile first server 7.0 WAS 8.5.5.5 it showing 404 not found error.
Security is enabled to connect to bluemix.
The same project I deployed on eclipse server the same API worked smoothly.
So, this is confirmed that .war file is not a problem, something is missing in mobile first server.

Answer (score 0):

The testtoken is available only in the MobileFirst development environment (Eclipse), and therefore is not available in remote server installations.

How do you get to it? What is this MobileFirst Bluemix environment? What guide did you follow the set it up?

Comment: https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/SSHSCD_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_oauth_test_token_endpoint.html     this guide I followed to get the test token. And do u mean test token only work with mobile first server in ecplise not with standalone mobile first server?

Comment: That's exactly what I mean.

Comment: I am not getting why it is like this @Idan Adar as how to test the app on mobile first server? and nothing specifically has been mentioned on the knowledge centre that it will work only with eclipse. Can you help me out to come up with some solution on this

Comment: You have to get your own token. The test token is available in order to bypass security in Studio so you could develop.

Comment: any API to generate own token? I do not get any link through which I can do that. I have my Bluemix credentials but don't know what request I need to send to generate token using API

Comment: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/authentication-security/authentication-concepts/oauth-based-security-model/

Comment: This document have development scenario. Doesn't tell how to acquire a token. What request I need to send and what parameter it should include. Pls help me to get rid of this problem.

Comment: The standalone mobilefirst server does not provide test tokens because it would be a security flaw. Test tokens are only for test servers. To test your standalone server, you need to answer all the challenges that the framework sends you. You can use the MobileFirst client SDK in a mobile app, or if not in a mobile app, see this: https://ibm.biz/BdHXT8

Comment: @Nathan H Any way to set up our own test server standalone one ?

Comment: Maybe your best option is to download the CLI (https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/install/#clui) and start the local server built-in.

Comment: We are not usingX.509 authentication we are using OAuth. No certificate is involved in there. Only token generation.